# jquery изменение строки

Tags: html, jquery

Функция отрабатывает полностью, если ее просто вызывать. Однако, если ее вызвать через Onclick, она быстро выполнится и все вернется обратно.

Почему откатываются изменения?

```
<body>

<form id="form-container" class="form-container">
    <label for="street">Street: </label><input type="text" id="street" value="">
    <label for="city">City: </label><input type="text" id="city" value="">
    <button id="submit-btn" onclick="loadData()">Submit</button>
</form>

<hr>

<h2 id="greeting" class="greeting">Where do you want to live?</h2>


<div class="wikipedia-container">
    <h3 id="wikipedia-header">Relevant Wikipedia Links</h3>
    <ul id="wikipedia-links">Type in an address above and find relevant Wikipedia articles here!</ul>
</div>


<div class="nytimes-container">
    <h3 id="nytimes-header">New York Times Articles</h3>
    <ul id="nytimes-articles" class="article-list">What's going on in your new city? Enter an address and hit submit and the NY Times will tell you here!</div>
</div>

<script src="js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```
function loadData() {
var $body = $('body');
var $wikiElem = $('#wikipedia-links');
var $nytHeaderElem = $('#nytimes-header');
var $nytElem = $('#nytimes-articles');
var $greeting = $('#greeting');

// clear out old data before new request
$wikiElem.text("");
$nytElem.text("");

// load streetview
var $streetStr = $('#street').val();
var $cityStr = $('#city').val();
var $address = $streetStr + ', ' + $cityStr;
$greeting.text('Ololol' + $address + '?');

var streetviewUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x400&location=' +$address + '';
$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="' + streetviewUrl + '">');

return false;};
```

Comment: а зачем вы возвращаете false из функции?

Comment: Для обучения использовал курсы Udacity, там был каркас функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно запретить стандартный сабмит формы, например, так:

```
$('#form-container').submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwVZOg

Comment: Спасибо большое.  О таком не знал.